# Who is the invisible princess on "Star Trek: Discovery"?

Tags: star-trek, character-identification, episode-identification, star-trek-discovery

In the "previously" clips for *Star Trek: Discovery* Season 2 Episode 13, there is apparently a princess who can turn herself invisible. She says "I ran away because I wasn't ready." in the clip. Tilly was featured prominently in the clip. What episode was that taken from?

Comment: Downvoted for an apparent total absence of research

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I am to believe [this article](https://screenrant.com/star-trek-discovery-season-2-story-shorts/) she's probably an alien from the *Short Trek* short "Runaway":

> The first Short Trek premiered in October of 2018 and followed a day in the life of Ensign Tilly. She has a frustrating conversation with her very overbearing mother that stokes her own self-doubt about joining the command program. Then, while eating alone in the mess hall, she discovers a young alien woman who’s used her ability to become invisible to stow away aboard the Star Trek: Discovery. After Tilly convinces Me Hani Ika Hali Ka Po she means her no harm, the young alien woman reveals she’s from a planet that’s about to achieve warp capability and is poised to join the greater space-faring community.

---

Found with the Google query `star trek discovery invisble princess`.